# How do I write a code that reads a text from the (textbox) and when I press my (button) it delets all DOTS in the Text?

Tags: c#, textbox

I have 2 Textboxes. One for a text you can paste in and one that will give you the same text but without any dots in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write above code in single line to replace textbox value.

```
private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(".", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this .

1 simple way

```
  private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Replace(".", "");
}
```

Comment: @7R4C3D if the solutioin helpt You , please mark it as answer or Vote Up